# probability that $YZ_1 > XZ_2$

Tags: probability

Suppose we have independent random variables $X,Y,Z$ where
$$ P(X=i) = 1/30 \quad i=1,\ldots,30 $$
$$ P(Y=i) = 1/20 \quad i=1,\ldots,20 $$
$$ P(Z=i) = 1/10 \quad i=0,\ldots,9 $$
How can I find $P(YZ_1 > XZ_2)$ analytically? Using a small script I found that this probability is $0.4035667$. Is there a clever way of computing it?

Comment: Are $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ independent with the same distribution as $Z$? If not, what are $Z_1$ and $Z_2$?

Comment: yeah exactly, they are independent and they follow distribution of  $Z$

Comment: "Is there a clever way of computing it?" No. Which begs the question of why would one ask this?

Answer (score 1):

Random variables $(X, Y, Z_1, Z_2)$ have joint pmf $f(x,y, z_1,z_2)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/discretejointpmfdiscrete.png))</sub>

You seek:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/discretejointpmfprob2.png))</sub>

which is $\approx 0.403567$  which matches your numerical work. I am not sure if this is a 'clever way of computing it', but it is quick and easy :)

**Notes**

1. The `Prob` function used above is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a probability generating function and use a CAS.

\begin{align*}
  G(x) &= \frac{1}{200\cdot 300}\left(20+\sum_{n=1}^{9}\frac{x^n-x^{21\, n}}{1-x^n}\right)\left(30+\sum_{m=1}^{9} \frac{\displaystyle x^{-m}-x^{-31\, m}}{\displaystyle 1-x^{-m}}\right)
\end{align*}
Expand $G(x)$ and collect all the coefficients of $x^i$ where $i>0$, and we will see that the sum of those coefficients is $\displaystyle \frac{12107}{30000}\approx 0.403567$